# GoogleMaps / GooglePlaces leaks memory on iPhone - swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps, memory-leaks

I'm currently encountering a problem within my app. I have a view on which I can search and select a place with the GoogleMaps / GooglePlaces SDK. I'm also using Google Autocomplete for completing the search string.

**The problem:** When I visit the first view, everything is still fine, but after I have entered a search string and press search, my memory usage increases for about 10-20 MB. When I unwind the view and save it, the memory won't be released and is still in my total memory. Therefore if I save a couple of places I'll get an overflow and the App will crash. 
Do you guys know where my problem is in the code? I'm already searching for hours...
I looked for Database request which sets up listeners but in fact nothing happens regarding this in these classes. Maybe it has something to do with Googlemaps, that it keeps up the connection?

I attached 2 screenshots from my app and the 2 classes for these are the following:

[image]
[image]

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class AddNewPlaceViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, LocateOnTheMap {

    //Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var googleMapsContainer: UIView!

    //Variables
    var googleMapsView: GMSMapView!
    var searchResultController: SearchResultsController!
    var resultsArray = [String]()

    //Result
    var locationAsCoords = [String:Double]()
    var locationAdress = String()

    //Error
    var alerts = Alerts()
    var alertActions = AlertActions()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        self.googleMapsView = GMSMapView(frame: self.googleMapsContainer.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(self.googleMapsView)

        searchResultController = SearchResultsController(view: self)
        searchResultController.delegate = self

        showSearchBar()
    }


    @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        if self.locationAdress.isEmpty {
            // Error message if no address has been searched
            NSLog("Event address ist empty.")
            let alert = alerts.alertNoLocationAddress
            let alertCancel = alertActions.alertActionCancel
            if(alert.actions.count == 0){
                alert.addAction(alertCancel)
            }
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {
            // exits with the saveAndUnwind segue
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("saveAndUnwind", sender: self)
        }
    }

    /**
     action for search location by address

     - parameter sender: button search location
     */
    @IBAction func searchWithAddress(sender: AnyObject) {
        showSearchBar()
    }

    /**
     Locate map with latitude and longitude after search location on UISearchBar

     - parameter lon:   longitude location
     - parameter lat:   latitude location
     - parameter title: title of address location
     */
    func locateWithLongitude(lon: Double, andLatitude lat: Double, andTitle title: String) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in

            self.googleMapsView.clear()

            let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
            let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)

            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(lat, longitude: lon, zoom: 15)
            self.googleMapsView.camera = camera

            marker.title = "\(title)"
            marker.map = self.googleMapsView
        }
    }

    func showSearchBar(){
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultController)
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    /**
     Searchbar when text change

     - parameter searchBar:  searchbar UI
     - parameter searchText: searchtext description

     We can use filters here in the autocompleteQuery
     */
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        let placeClient = GMSPlacesClient()
        placeClient.autocompleteQuery(searchText, bounds: nil, filter: nil) { (results, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            self.resultsArray.removeAll()
            if results == nil {
                return
            }

            for result in results! {
                if let result = result as? GMSAutocompletePrediction {
                    self.resultsArray.append(result.attributedFullText.string)
                }
            }

            self.searchResultController.reloadDataWithArray(self.resultsArray)

        }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if(segue.identifier == "saveAndUnwind"){

            //Pushing the data to the other view controller
            let destViewControllerCreateEventTable  = segue.destinationViewController as! CreateEventTableViewController

            destViewControllerCreateEventTable.locationAsCoords["latitude"] = self.locationAsCoords["latitude"]
            destViewControllerCreateEventTable.locationAsCoords["longitude"] = self.locationAsCoords["longitude"]
            destViewControllerCreateEventTable.locationAdress = self.locationAdress

            destViewControllerCreateEventTable.locationLabel.text = self.locationAdress
            destViewControllerCreateEventTable.locationLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

        }

    }


}
```

//

```
import UIKit

protocol LocateOnTheMap{
    func locateWithLongitude(lon:Double, andLatitude lat:Double, andTitle title: String)
}

class SearchResultsController: UITableViewController {

    var searchResults: [String]!
    var delegate: LocateOnTheMap!

    var addNewPlaceReference = AddNewPlaceViewController()

    init(view: AddNewPlaceViewController ){
        super.init(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        addNewPlaceReference = view
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.searchResults = Array()
        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.searchResults.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.searchResults[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
            // 1
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            // 2
            let correctedAddress:String! = self.searchResults[indexPath.row].stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.symbolCharacterSet())
            let url = NSURL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(correctedAddress)&sensor=false")

            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                // 3
                do {
                    if data != nil{
                        let dic = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary

                        let lat = dic["results"]?.valueForKey("geometry")?.valueForKey("location")?.valueForKey("lat")?.objectAtIndex(0) as! Double
                        let lon = dic["results"]?.valueForKey("geometry")?.valueForKey("location")?.valueForKey("lng")?.objectAtIndex(0) as! Double
                        // 4
                        self.delegate.locateWithLongitude(lon, andLatitude: lat, andTitle: self.searchResults[indexPath.row])

                        self.addNewPlaceReference.locationAdress = self.searchResults[indexPath.row]
                        self.addNewPlaceReference.locationAsCoords["latitude"] = lat
                        self.addNewPlaceReference.locationAsCoords["longitude"] = lon

                    }

                }catch {
                    print("Error")
                }
            }
            // 5
            task.resume()
    }


    func reloadDataWithArray(array:[String]){
        self.searchResults = array
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Comment: did you find the solution how to free up memory?